# Quickly and efficiently switch array elements

Tags: javascript, arrays

I am trying to swap the data within these arrays.

My data will look something like this. In production this array can and will be several times bigger.

```
var data = [
    [13.418946862220764, 52.50055852688439],
    [13.419011235237122, 52.50113000479732],
    [13.419756889343262, 52.50171780290061],
    [13.419885635375975, 52.50237416816131],
    [13.420631289482117, 52.50294888790448]
]
```

Currently my switching code looks like the below.

```
var temp;

for(var i = 0;i < data.length;i++) {
    temp = array[i][0];
    array[i][0] = array[i][1];
    array[i][1] = temp;
}
```

What I am trying to figure out is if this the most efficient way to do this and/or if any improvements are possible.

Please understand that even the slightest improvement will matter.

Comment: Your switching code does not actually switch the elements, rather it just puts the second element of those sub-arrays into the first one.

Comment: You could try caching `var row = array[i];`

Comment: What is expected result of `data`, and `temp`?  _"What I am trying to figure out is if this the most efficient way to do this"_ What do you mean by "most efficient"? Least amount of time required to complete the process?

Comment: Please specify the efficiency either space or time. Also specify memory constraints .

Comment: You code looks perfectly fine (everything is in place), and you make just enough memory read/write as needed

Comment: What is the `array` variable? Did you mean `data`? From a pure performance standpoint, if that is what you mean by "efficient", your current code is probably optimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use a more functional approach:

```
var switched = data.map(function (arr) {
  return [arr[1], arr[0]];
});
```

If you use ES2015, you can even do that in one line:

```
const switched = data.map((arr) => [arr[1], arr[0]]);
```

Comment: even shorter with destructuring: `data.map(([a, b]) => [b, a])`

Comment: This will double the memory footprint by creating a new array

Comment: @RegisPortalez It is not at all clear that it will. What new array are you suggesting will be created? The parameter destructuring `[a, b]` does not create a new array; it merely extracts `a` and `b` from the parameter.

Comment: Switched and arr will both continue to live in memory until they are collected. So in the best case, arr is not used anymore quite quickly, and therefore will be collected. But garbage collection passes takes cpu time, which you save by making the switch in place

Answer (score 0):

If you want to stick with a loop:

```
for(var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    data[i] = [data[i][1], data[i][0]];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You code looks perfectly fine, and you don't need any further "optimization".

As always, a benchmark is always the good way to find out who is faster:

```js
var arr = (function() {
    var res = [];
    for(var i = 0; i < 100000; ++i) {
        res[i] = [Math.random(), Math.random()];
    }
    return res;
}());

var swap_in_place = function() {
    for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
        var tmp = arr[i][0];
        arr[i][0] = arr[i][1];
        arr[i][1] = tmp;
    }
};


var swap_map = function() {
    arr = arr.map(function(elem) {return [elem[1], elem[0]]; });
};

var runBench = function(name, f) {
    var start = new Date().getTime();
    for(var i = 0; i < 50; ++i) {
        f();
    }
    var stop = new Date().getTime();
    console.log(name + " took: " + (stop - start));
};


runBench("in_place", swap_in_place);
runBench("map", swap_map);
```

in my firefox latest (windows 10 x64), I get (quite consistently) 16 for in place, vs 350 for map version, meaning you get a **20x speed down** by using map instead of your own version.

You might think this is due to the fact that this snippet is embedded in a iframe and so on, so I ran it in node (4.5.0), which is built on top of V8, and I get the same results:

[image]

I think that the Jitter can't be smart enough to properly inline the function in the map version, or deduce it operates on the same memory without side effect. Thefore, the Jitter has to allocate a full new array to store the intermediate results, then loop over it with a function call (meaning register save/restore stall at each iteration), and then either:

- copy back the entire data to `arr`
- move the reference (probably what happens), but the garbage collector has to collect the entire temporary array.

The map function might also trigger reallocation of the temporary, which is extremely expensive.